# Understanding Enclosing Environment

Tags: r

I have the following code

```
new_counter <- function(){
  ij <- 0
  function(){
    ij <<- ij+1
    ij
  }
}

counter_one <- new_counter()
counter_two <- new_counter()

counter_one()
counter_one()
```

from this [tutorial](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#functional-programming).

They write:

> The counters get around the “fresh start” limitation by not modifying
>   variables in their local environment. Since the changes are made in
>   the unchanging parent (or enclosing) environment, they are preserved
>   across function calls.

This is what I think is going on: The `new_counter` function is created in the `.GlobalEnv` (`enclosing environment`) as well as the `counter_one` function. But the `execution environment` of `new_counter` function is one level higher than the counter_one functions. This is usually temporary but this time it is not since we have an enclosure function.

But how can I see 'this' *enclosing enviroment* and that they are one level apart? Using (pryr) `where` and *environment* delivers for both functions the global environment.

EDIT:
They talk about two different environments:

1. 'in theire local environment'
2. 'in the unchainging parent environment'

So to me these are two different environments but if they differ they probably have a different name! How can I find out the name? Using

```
where("new_counter")
where("counter_one")
```

both deliver the global environment but looking in the enumeration above this must be two different ones.

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you are asking, can you try to explain further / differently?

Comment: I edited my question and hope it is more understandable.

Comment: “Using … `environment` delivers for both functions the global environment.” — No, it absolutely doesn’t. You’ll get different environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should hopefully clarify what is happening.  Note that the enclosing environment of `new_counter` is the global environment but the environments of `counter_one` and `counter_two` are the environments within the two execution instances of `new_counter`.  Normally a function's enclosing environment is its lexical environment (the environment where it is defined) but in some situations this varies.

```
new_counter <- function(){
  e <- environment()
  print(e)
  ij <- 0
  function(){
    ij <<- ij+1
    ij
  }
}

counter_one <- new_counter()  # A
counter_two <- new_counter()  # B

counter_one()
counter_one()

environment(new_counter) # global environment

environment(counter_one) # see output of A
environment(counter_two) # see output of B
```

Here is a simpler example that shows that a function can be located in one environment yet its enclosing environment can be a different environment.  In this case `f` is in the global environment; however, its enclosing environment is `e` and not the global environment.

```
e <- new.env()
e$x <- 1
x <- 2
f <- function() x
environment(f) <- e
f() 
## [1] 1
```

There are actually several environments that one can consider.  Let us add some instrumentation to `f` in the last example.

```
f <- function() {
       ee <- environment()
       print(ee)
       x
}
e <- new.env()   
e$x <- 1   
x <- 2
environment(f) <- e
f() # displays ee and then the value of x which is 1
```

These are the environments:

- the enclosing environment of `f` is `e` since we set it that way
- the lexical environment is the environment that f is located in.  It is the global environment here.  Usually the lexical environment and the enclosing environment are the same but because we reset the enclosing environment of `f` in this case they are different.
- the execution environment within the function `f` while it is running. In this case it is `ee`.   The executation environment will be destroyed when `f` completes unless there are  still pointers to it from the outside.  Each time `f` is run a new execution environment is created so `ee` takes on a new value each time `f` is run.

Thus in this example there is `e`, the global environment and one execution environment each time that `f` is run.

There is some discussion here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

**Update**  Some clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Without `pryr`, you can see the environments with something like:

```
environment(counter_one)
# <environment: 0x00000000078be648>
environment(counter_two)
# <environment: 0x00000000078bf148>
ls(env=environment(counter_two))
# [1] "ij"
counter_one()
# [1] 1
get("ij", envir = environment(counter_one))
# [1] 1
get("ij", envir = environment(counter_two))
# [1] 0
```

Furthermore, you can change the values of variables within that environment:

```
assign("abc", 123, envir = environment(counter_two))
ls(envir = environment(counter_one))
# [1] "ij"
ls(envir = environment(counter_two))
# [1] "abc" "ij"
```

Comment: ah ok. <environment: 0x00000000078be648> and <environment: 0x00000000078bf148> answers my question. thanks